# Nuget commandline - extracting compatible assemblies from package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I would like to download a list of assemblies as referenced by (as an example) the package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/). I want to download them all in order to get a list of all the specific assemblies compatible with NetStandard 2.0.

What I did was to run from the command line in an empty folder the command

```
nuget install Microsoft.AspNetCore -Version 2.2.0 -DependencyVersion HighestPatch -Framework net472 -OutputDirectory .\packages
```

I got all the dependant packages in the (newly created) subfolder packages.

Is there an automatic way to extract the dlls from the lib subfolders which are compatible with .Net 4.7.2? Currently inside the packages are present also versions specific to .Net Core.

Like a globbing path smart enough to find the compatible versions.

Usually this is done by Visual Studio, but I need to certify a list of compatible assemblies separately from the Visual Studio project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dotnet new console`
2. Edit the csproj and change the `<TargetFramework>` to `net472`
3. `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore` (or while editing the csproj add the relevant `PackageReference`)
4. `dotnet publish`

The `bin\Debug\publish` directory will contain all the dlls compatible with net472.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I didn't think about creating a dummy project just to resolve dependencies on another. It works perfectly.